# MIssing IMAP folders

Tags: imap, thunderbird, dovecot

I've recently encountered an issue with my IMAP folders on Dovecot 2.0.19. When I telnet into my account and perform a list, I get the following response:

```
A list "*" "*"
* LIST (\Unmarked) "." "INBOX"
A OK List completed.
```

However I know there are subfolders here and have examined the server directly via SSH and strangely:

```
a select INBOX.Clients
* OK [CLOSED] Previous mailbox closed.
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft \*)] Flags permitted.
* 0 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1394028715] UIDs valid
* OK [UIDNEXT 1] Predicted next UID
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 1] Highest
a OK [READ-WRITE] Select completed.
```

Just not sure why a LIST is not giving me a full list. This is also affecting connecting to my IMAP via Thunderbird as I can only access my INBOX. Any ideas on how to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Does `list "" "*"` give a different result? The `LIST` command takes two arguments, reference and pattern, and I'm not sure what a reference of `"*"` would mean.

Comment: Thanks legoscia. Yeh - I get the same response:
`a list "" "*"
* LIST (\Unmarked) "." "INBOX"
a OK List completed.`

Comment: Seems I can also subscribe to these folders as well!!

Answer (score 0):

I get results now, I achieved this by removing the quotation marks. Talking to the Server via PHP and `fsockopen/fputs` this worked:

```
fputs($socket, "A5 LIST * % " . NEWLINE);
```